# Closing CSV file to read it again?

Tags: arcpy, csv, error-000725, error-000728

Apparently, I cannot close the csv file, so that it cannot be opened to be processed. How can I solve my problem?

I get a list (A)  from my calculations such that:

```
A = [[1.0,153.0016399,-27.6402685],[2.0,153.0783324,-27.4669576]]
```

I  want to save it as csv file in order to read it and create a shapefile from XY. Creating csv file is successful and it is saved correctly, however it can not be immediately used to create a shapefile. When I copy this csv file into another file, it works fine. I need to do it 1000 times so I cannot copy it each step. My csv file looks like:

```
ID,x,y
1.0,153.0016399,-27.6402685
2.0,153.0783324,-27.4669576
```

and here is my code:

```
import csv
import arcpy
def MakeXY(x):        
    arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\...\\"
    arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
    outWorkspace = "C:\\...\\"
    try:
        in_Table = x
        x_coords = "x"
        y_coords = "y"
        out_Layer_0 = "test"
        spRef = r"C:\\...\\Coordinate Systems\\WGS 1984.prj"

        # Make the XY event layer
        arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(in_Table, x_coords, y_coords, out_Layer_0, spRef)
        # Save to a layer file
        arcpy.FeatureClassToShapefile_conversion(out_Layer_0, outWorkspace)          
    except Exception as err:
        print(err.args[0])
A = [[1.0,153.0016399,-27.6402685],[2.0,153.0783324,-27.4669576]]
A_header = ['ID','x','y']           
writer = csv.writer(file(os.path.join('C:\\...\\', 'Mylist.csv'),'wb'))
writer.writerows([A_header])
writer.writerows(A)
f = open('C:\\...\\Mylist.csv')
f.close()
MakeXY('Mylist.csv')
```

and here is the error I get:

Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000728: Field x does not exist within table
ERROR 000728: Field y does not exist within table
WARNING 000725: Layer Name or Table View: Dataset test already exists.
Failed to execute (MakeXYEventLayer).

Comment: What happens when you remove your try/except statements so that we can see the full error with its line number?

Comment: As indicated by the accepted answer this is a pure Python question that has probably already been asked and answered at [so].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not opening/closing the file properly. This is how it should be done (check the `csv` [help page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)):

```
A = [[1.0,153.0016399,-27.6402685],[2.0,153.0783324,-27.4669576]]
A_header = ['ID','x','y']
csv_path = os.path.join(r'C:\GIS\Temp', 'Mylist.csv')

with open(csv_path,'wb') as csv_file:
    data_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    data_writer.writerows([A_header])
    data_writer.writerows(A)

f = open(csv_path)
f.read().splitlines()
#['ID,x,y', '1.0,153.0016399,-27.6402685', '2.0,153.0783324,-27.4669576']    
f.close()
```

The error message says that you don't have `x` & `y` columns in `.csv` file. Make sure you do write and close the file properly using the `with` statement.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to save a CSV file each time, then you can just use an `InsertCursor` directly.

```
import arcpy
import os

outWorkspace = r"C:\data"
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

counter = 1
main_loop_that_does_calculaton:

    uniqueName = "calculation{0}.shp".format(counter)

    arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(outWorkspace, uniqueName, "POINT", spatial_reference=sr)
    arcpy.AddField_management(os.path.join(outWorkspace, uniqueName), "refID", "FLOAT")

    points = [[1.0,153.0016399,-27.6402685],[2.0,153.0783324,-27.4669576]]

    insertCursor = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(os.path.join(outWorkspace, uniqueName), ("SHAPE@XY", "refID"))

    for point in points:
        insertCursor.insertRow([(point[1], point[2]),point[0]])

    counter += 1
    del insertCursor
```

Without seeing the rest of your code, I'm not sure how to create the `uniqueName` for the shapefile. But you would just want to create a unique name based on the calculation you are doing. It could just be a simple counter.